# My backend module work in window but not in linux

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1

when i access the module in my linux server using this link

domain/index.php/AdminLog/adminhtml_adminlog/index/key/0ae0ba00e17e37611025f3cd9f49a395/

it redirect me to frondend and display 404 error, how can i debug this? which files should i post here?

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <RayMan_AdminLog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <title>Admin log module</title>
        </RayMan_AdminLog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <adminlog>
                <class>RayMan_AdminLog_Model</class>            
                <resourceModel>adminlog_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </adminlog>
            <adminlog_mysql4>
                <class>RayMan_AdminLog_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <adminlog>
                        <table>admin_log</table>
                    </adminlog>
                </entities>
            </adminlog_mysql4>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <adminlog>
                <class>RayMan_AdminLog_Helper</class>
            </adminlog>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <adminlog>
                <class>RayMan_AdminLog_Block</class>
            </adminlog>
        </blocks>
        <default>
            <adminlog>
                <general>
                    <enable>1</enable>
                </general>
            </adminlog>
        </default>

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminlog>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>RayMan_AdminLog</module>
                    <frontName>adminlog</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminlog>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <adminlog>
                <file>adminlog.xml</file>
            </adminlog>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <sales_order_invoice_pay>
            <observers>
                <rayman_adminlog_controller_action_predispatch_observer>
                    <class>Rayman_Adminlog_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sales_order_invoice_pay</method>
                </rayman_adminlog_controller_action_predispatch_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_pay>
    </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

layout.xml located at "app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminlog_adminhtml_adminlog_index>
        <update handle="adminlog_adminlog_index"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="adminlog" template="adminlog/adminlog.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminlog_adminhtml_adminlog_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `config.xml` file and the name and path of your admin controller file? my money is on a case-sensitivity file name issue.

Comment: post updated....

Comment: check your file name "AdminLog" try to like "Adminlog"

Comment: Sometimes  if you have a capital letter in the module name it doesn't work on LINUX OS. I mean Modulename is ok, ModuleName is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firs of all, if your admin route name is `adminlog` lowercase (`<frontName>adminlog</frontName>`) the admin url should be `domain/index.php/adminlog/adminhtml_adminlog/index/key/abcd...`

Second, the path to your admin controller should be `RayMan/AdminLog/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminlogController.php`

I bet your controller path is `RayMan/AdminLog/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminLogController.php`.

Here they are side by side so you can see the differences.

`RayMan/AdminLog/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminlogController.php` - the correct one
`RayMan/AdminLog/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminLogController.php` - the one I think you have

Comment: Yes, you are right. My admin module display now, but the grid and database row still not displaying. Seems there are other problems.

Comment: Check the layout file. For example the layout handle for the index action should be `<adminlog_adminhtml_adminlog_index>`

Comment: i can't still fix the problems :(

Comment: Try going step by step through this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue in one of my custom module.

For long time my module worked correctly but after applying the SUPEE-6788 patch I started getting 404 error on admin controller of my module.

**Erroneous controller name and content**

*File name* : HomePageGridManagerController.php

```
class Mynamespace_HomePageGridManager_Adminhtml_Homepagegridmanageradmin_HomePageGridManagerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
```

**Correct controller name and content**

*File name* : HomepagegridmanagerController.php

```
class Mynamespace_HomePageGridManager_Adminhtml_Homepagegridmanager_HomepagegridmanagerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
```

Notice the case sensitiveness.Though this was not related to SUPEE-6788 but created the problem. So always double check your file names and test the extension or custom module on Windows as well as Linux.